# Make an option of jQuery ComboBox not selectable

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, combobox, onclick

just like the title says...I have a combobox, whose options are filled with web service call, activated on the click event.
I need to handle that list and make an option of that list (just the one whose value starts with "-" not selectable).
The "-" works a separator between one option group and the second following one.

So let's say I have this combo:

```
<select id="authority" class="selectauthority" style="width: 300px;" onclick="DisableSpecificOption()" name="authority">
<option value=""> </option>
<option value="001">Federal Bureau </option>
<option value="003">Police </option>
<option value="-1">-</option>
<option value="004">Army </option>
<option value="018">Navy </option>
<option value="018">CIA </option>
<option value="018">NSA </option>
</select>
```

As far as I know make the option disabled should be enough...I tried several scripts but I wasn't able to obtain my goal.

[My Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DioBrando/th6y2cko/6/)

Thank you in advance

*edit*
Since I have to use it in more than one selector and function I wrote a general one.
[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DioBrando/th6y2cko/18/)

Hope it helps somebody

Comment: And you of course don't check console for syntax errors? Take a look at [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/th6y2cko/7/). Extra `()` cause syntax error.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
$('#authority option[value="-1"]').attr("disabled","disabled")
```

or

```
$('#name option:contains("-")').attr("disabled","disabled")
```

Comment: There is no critical problems with this line in original code. Once again: the problem is in extra `()`

Comment: prop, attar should work the same...I use the first one to reach more IE old versions' compatibility.

Thank u very much buddy, I'm supposed to use this function in a bigger one so couldn't see nocive parenthesis :|